# Wifi connectivity issues in Ubuntu 14.04 [HP pavilion 15 series]

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I am very much new to ubuntu and this communtiy and i recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 (alongside windows 10) on my newly purchased laptop(hp pavilion 15-ab032tx).

There's some serious issues with the wifi connections in ubuntu.

If I am sitting very close(1 -2 feet) to my router it diplays the connection but gives a very low connection speed.

If I go to a distance more than say 5 feet, it shows the connection to be out of range.
I followed some previous threads regarding this issue but i haven't been able to solve the problem.

I also made some changes to the power management of my wireless card( as instructed in another thread) but it also didn't work.

(NOTE: WiFi works perfectly fine on windows 10)

here's some information regarding my wireless card:-

```
 ***-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 70:77:81:12:70:59
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.16.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c6100000-c6103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:ae:32:43
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:64 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff**
```

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/543602/unstable-wifi-connection-ubuntu-14-04/543626#543626

Comment: **mrinal** Could you give some feed-back to @chili555's question?

Comment: thanks for the reply @chili555. i typed and ran the mentioned code on the terminal and rebooted my device but the problem doesn't seem to go. it still doesn't connect when i am sitting in my room although it gives a good enough connection when i am sitting right next to my router.

Comment: do you suggest uninstalling 14.04 and installing 15.04 on my device?

Answer (score 0):

1. First upgrade the kernel to 3.16 as shown in accepted answer at this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. Reboot into the new 3.16.x by command `sudo reboot`.
3. After rebooting, run `sudo apt-get -f autoremove`
4. Now we have to remove old kernel, for that, first list the kernels currently present by command `sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-image`
5. It gives a list of kernels, identify the older version, for example `linux-image-3.11`
6. Give command `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.14`
7. Now give command : `sudo update-grub2`
8. Now reboot by `sudo reboot`
9. Now we have to install realtek driver. For that follow below commands :

   - `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git`
   - `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new`
   - `cd rtlwifi_new`
   - `make`
   - `sudo make install`
   - `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be`
   - `sudo modprobe rtl8723be`