# wifi is very poor and unstable --> after installing ubuntu mate 16.04 in HP Pavilion 15-ab032tx Notebook

Tags: networking, drivers, hp, mate

I have installed ubuntu mate 16.04 in my HP Pavilion 15-ab032tx Notebook. (windows 8.1 is also there though i have dual booted).
I have updated and upgraded by:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade` - in terminal
then I found wifi signals shows very poor and often disconnects. But when i log into 'Windows' wifi gets full signal strength and stable.

---

then I searched lot for solution
I tried:
 [Unstable Wifi Connection Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543602/unstable-wifi-connection-ubuntu-14-04/543626#543626)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper 
 and many more methods
but still no solution
I am new to ubuntu..
 help me to fix this please. thanks..

---

some informations that may require for solution are below:
hardware info:
after typing `sudo lshw` in terminal

```
`my pc                      
    description: Notebook
    product: HP Pavilion Notebook
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: ###
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=PAV X=Null sku=### uuid=###      



           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                logical name: wlo1
                version: 00
                serial: d8:5d:e2:62:c4:65
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:18 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c6100000-c6103fff
```

`
and
product info:
http://support.hp.com/sk-en/document/c04700593

I am extremely very sorry for the long post
please help me to fix this problem. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: Does your current driver contain the *ant_sel* parameter? Please check: `modinfo rtl8723be` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 modinfo rtl8723be output is as below:
https://s32.postimg.org/cholo3j2d/Screenshot_at_2016_07_09_18_42_03.png
i have sent you the screenshot of modinfo rtl8723be output

thanks...

Comment: @chili555   yes 

i think you want this info-

ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)) and [edit] your post, when you want to add information. File or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) is much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for the suggestion... i will try to maintain form the next...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you try, from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the performance is improved.

Comment: I tried as you said but same performance . No improvement . Please show me another way to fix this problem.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I suggest you try instead: `ant_sel=1`

Comment: it worked... thanks a ton...  you made my day...

Comment: Wifi works but bluetooth doesn't work. Sorry, I didn't check it earlier. Please help me to fix this. I even don't know if wifi and bluetooth uses same hardware or not. It shows in the specification of my hp that, wireless connectivity:- 802.11b/g/n (1x1) and Bluetooth 4.0 combo (Miracast compatible), WiDi

Comment: I think that bluetooth is the subject for a new question. Be sure to include the result of: `dmesg | grep -i blue` Missing firmware?? Glad the wireless is working as expected.

Comment: I have posted the bluetooth problem in http://askubuntu.com/questions/797635/bluetooth-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-mate-16-04-on-hp-pavilion-15-ab032tx-notebook