# Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on HP Pavilion 15-ab032tx Notebook

Tags: bluetooth, hp, ubuntu-mate

When I click on the Bluetooth icon, panel opens but when I search/scan for devices, no device found and similarly nobody can find me from another device.

I have run `dmesg | grep -i blue` in terminal. Here's the output:

```
[    2.257690] usb 1-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   13.262616] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   13.262631] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.262633] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.262635] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.262645] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.768062] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   13.768065] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   13.886089] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   31.058448] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.058451] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   31.058455] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   33.062823] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c56 tx timeout
[   51.030259] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   51.030272] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   51.030278] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

How can I fix this?

Below is the output o `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
```

Comment: Is the bluetooth turned on or off? `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555  the above command output is:-  0: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

Comment: @chili555 1: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

Comment: I see nothing wrong and therefor fixable, although I am not very experienced in bluetooth. I am sorry that I have no other suggestions.

Comment: @chili555 thanks alot for your suggestions... though i am new to ubuntu and askubuntu.. can you please give me reference of someone who is experienced in bluetooth..

Comment: @morhook can you fix my problem?

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question to more fully explain the problem. Does your device see other devices? Do others see you? Can you see but not connect? Do you connect but drop or...what?

Comment: @chili555 I have edited my question.